# Path-ordered integrals with dirac deltas

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

When calculating integrals with delta functions, the integration domains are usually rectangular. However, recently, I encountered a set of time ordered integrals over Dirac deltas of the following form:
$$ \int_0^1 dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_2 \int_0^{t_2} dt_3 \int_0^{t_3} dt_4 K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4) \delta(t_1-t_2)\delta(t_3-t_4) $$
$$ \int_0^1 dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_2 \int_0^{t_2} dt_3 \int_0^{t_3} dt_4 K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4) \delta(t_1-t_3)\delta(t_2-t_4) $$
$$ \int_0^1 dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_2 \int_0^{t_2} dt_3 \int_0^{t_3} dt_4 K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4) \delta(t_1-t_4)\delta(t_3-t_2) $$
Where $K(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)$ is some smooth function of the arguments.

For convenience, I set $K=1$ and evaluated these integrals in mathematica. All three of them are zero! This answer makes no sense to me, because suppose I add up these three integrals (for $K=1$), I would get:
$$ \int_0^1 dt_1 \int_0^{t_1} dt_2 \int_0^{t_2} dt_3 \int_0^{t_3} dt_4 \bigg(\delta(t_1-t_2)\delta(t_3-t_4)+\delta(t_1-t_3)\delta(t_2-t_4)+\delta(t_1-t_4)\delta(t_2-t_3)\bigg) $$
This expression is manifestly symmetric wrt to all permutation of $t_i$'s. Therefore, the time ordered integral can be transformed into a regular integral over rectangular domains:
$$ \frac{1}{24} \int_0^1 dt_1 \int_0^{1} dt_2 \int_0^{1} dt_3 \int_0^{1} dt_4 \bigg(\delta(t_1-t_2)\delta(t_3-t_4)+\delta(t_1-t_3)\delta(t_2-t_4)+\delta(t_1-t_4)\delta(t_2-t_3)\bigg) $$
This integral evaluates to $\frac{1}{8}$ instead of zero.

So the question is: which one is the correct answer? And more generally, how should I think about Dirac deltas rigorously in time-ordered integrals?

Comment: How does one define the functional $\int_0^\infty \delta(x)\,dx$?  It isn't uniquely defined.

Comment: The integral as stated is not defined (as Mark Viola has pointed out). You have to go back a few steps in your calculation to understand how the expression came about and at which step the problem appeared. You integral looks like it might be a physics problem and there sometimes stuff like causality comes to rescue...

Answer (score 2):

- We can replace simplex integration region with a rectangular domain $[0,1]^4$ if we multiply the integrand with 
  $$ \theta(t_1\!-\!t_2)\theta(t_2\!-\!t_3)\theta(t_3\!-\!t_4), \tag{A}$$
  where $\theta$ denotes the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Multiplying [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) with discontinuous functions is not mathematically well-defined.
- Nevertheless, we cannot resist to heuristically calculate what would happen with OP's integral in the case $K=1$ if we assume that [$\theta(0)=\frac{1}{2}$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61176/2451).

  1. If we first integrate over $t_1$ & $t_4$ the first integrand becomes $$\theta(0)\theta(t_2\!-\!t_3)\theta(0).$$ The integrations over $t_2$ & $t_3$ then yield $\frac{1}{8}$.
  2. If we first integrate over $t_3$ & $t_4$ the second integrand becomes $$\theta(t_1\!-\!t_2)^2\theta(t_2\!-\!t_1)
     ~=~\frac{1}{8}\delta_{t_1,t_2}~=~0\text{ a.e.}$$ 
     Here $\delta_{t_1,t_2}$ is the [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)$^1$, which is zero [almost everywhere (a.e.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere). The integrations over $t_1$ & $t_2$ then yield $0$.
  3. Similarly, if we first integrate over $t_3$ & $t_4$ the third integrand becomes 
     $$\theta(t_1\!-\!t_2)\theta(0)\theta(t_2\!-\!t_1)
     ~=~\frac{1}{8}\delta_{t_1,t_2}~=~0\text{ a.e.}$$
     The integrations over $t_1$ & $t_2$ then yield $0$.

  Hence the total integral is heuristically $\frac{1}{8}+0+0=\frac{1}{8}$, which agrees with OP's symmetrization argument.

--

$^1$The Kronecker delta function $\delta_{t_1,t_2}$ should not be confused with the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) $\delta(t_1\!-\!t_2)$.

Comment: +1. I'll add that this has some physical content, it corresponds to passing to a *symmetric* approximate identity rather than an arbitrary approximate identity. As mentioned in https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/61338/108628 (an answer you wrote to the question you linked), this is closely related to the Cauchy principal value, it is not just a superficial resemblance.

Answer (score 0):

One trick:

Whenever you have $\delta (t_1 - t_2) \delta (t_3 - t_4)K(t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4)$ you can replace the integrals to be over just two variables, $t_1$ and $t_3$, say, and argument $K(t_1, t_1, t_3, t_3)$.

Comment: Hey David, that's exactly what I thought would be true. But for some reason, mathematica didn't agree with that, which is why I am confused.

Comment: I suspect this is a problem with the algorithmics in *Mathematica* rather than a misunderstanding of actual mathematics.